# Как декрементировать переменную при нажатии кнопки?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне надо, чтобы переменная stamina уменьшалась на одну (декрементировалась) каждый кадр, пока нажата кнопка Shift

Я написсал такой код:

```
public float stamina = 1000;

public void Update()
{
     if (Input.GetButtonDown("LeftShift"));
     { 
          stamina--;
          stamina--;
     }
}
```

Однако, стамина не уменьшается, подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы переменная уменьшалась каждый кадр, во время нажатии кнопки

Причем, когда я сделал с помощью функции Update чтобы переменная просто инкрементировалась, это работало

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, как мне надо

и еще, если получиться, как установить максимальное значение для переменной типа float (чтобы, например, больше 1000 она не могла увеличиваться)?

Comment: не дублируйте код `stamina -= 2`, ну и вот это почитайте https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html

Answer (score 2):

Из документации Unity: "It will not return true until the user has released the key and pressed it again". Поясню, за одно нажатие будет происходить только один инкремент. Не уверен, но возможно подойдет Input.GetKeyDown.
Заведите отдельное поле с максимальным значением стамины и увеличивайте значение, до тех пор пока оно не превосходит максимальное.